# How to Loop through another index of jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a jquery object which store all the information of a table cells. When i log the object the following content shows up but when i loop them i only get the first line of the log. Please help me how i can loop the remaining line of the object

[image]

Comment: How are we supposed to help you without seeing your code?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Show your jquery code, so that we can help you.

Comment: function Trigger2(clicked_id)
        {
            var $selectedCells = $('table').tableCellsSelection('selectedCells');
         

           
            for (var i = 0; i < $selectedCells.length; i++) {
                $selectedCells.each(function (i) {
                    var row = $selectedCells.parent().index();
                    var column = $selectedCells.index();
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += i + " Row " + row + " Column :" + column + "<br>";
                });
            }
        }

Comment: $selectedCells stores selected table attributes shown in above picture. In the above picture i have selected 4 table cell. In console.log($selectedCells) it shows up 4 selected attributes

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, i've got the answer.

```
function Trigger2(clicked_id) {
        var $selectedCells = $('table').tableCellsSelection('selectedCells');
        $selectedCells.each(function(i) {
            var row = $selectedCells.eq(i).parent().index();
            var column = $selectedCells.eq(i).index();
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += i + " Row " + row + " Column :" + column + "<br>";
        });
}
```